# OPENSSL_Uplink(00007FFB23D4AD30,08): unimplemented function

Tags: qt, openssl

when I use openssl apis with SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx,CACERT,NULL) in windows but run my projects appear OPENSSL_Uplink(00007FFB23D4AD30,08): unimplemented function.
so Has anyone encountered this problem and how to deal with it?

```
int err;
    int listen_sd;
    int sd;
    struct sockaddr_in sa_serv;
    struct sockaddr_in sa_cli;
    int client_len;
    SSL_CTX* ctx;
    SSL*     ssl;
    X509*    client_cert;
    char*    str;
    char     buf [4096];

    WSADATA wsaData;

    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsaData) != 0){
        printf("WSAStartup()fail:%d/n",GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    SSL_load_error_strings();            /*为打印调试信息作准备*/
    OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms();        /*初始化*/
    const SSL_METHOD *meth = TLSv1_server_method();  /*采用什么协议(SSLv2/SSLv3/TLSv1)在此指定*/
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new (meth);
    CHK_NULL(ctx);

    SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx,SSL_VERIFY_PEER,NULL);   /*验证与否*/
  #if 1
    SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx,CACERT,NULL); /*若验证,则放置CA证书*/ 
   #endif
```

Comment: Have you compiled and linked applink.c into your application? See https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/OPENSSL_Applink.html

Comment: like this:#include"openssl/applink.c"?

Comment: Yes that should do it